# constructor or ngoninit is not calling when used router.navigate in ionic 4 with angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic4

i am using ionic 4 with angular
i am navigating from home page to login when login status is false

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
```

and also from login page to home page after login

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
```

my router modile is

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
path: '',
redirectTo: 'home',
pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
path: 'home',
loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule)
},
{
path: 'list',
loadChildren: () => import('./list/list.module').then(m => m.ListPageModule)
},
{ path: 'acceptordermodalpage', loadChildren: './acceptordermodalpage/acceptordermodalpage.module#AcceptordermodalpagePageModule'},
{ path: 'newordermodalpage', loadChildren: './newordermodalpage/newordermodalpage.module#NewordermodalpagePageModule' },
{ path: 'rejectordermodalpage', loadChildren: './rejectordermodalpage/rejectordermodalpage.module#RejectordermodalpagePageModule' },
{ path: 'orderdetailsmodalpage', loadChildren: './orderdetailsmodalpage/orderdetailsmodalpage.module#OrderdetailsmodalpagePageModule' },
{ path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' }
];

@NgModule({
imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

now the problem is when i navigate from one page/component to another page/component the ngoninit or the constructor of destination page/component doesn't fire

but when i navigate using routerlink it works

```
[routerLink]="[p.url]"
```

i found some suggestion in online searching and i applied them

in router module in changed to

```
imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules, onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' })
],
```

i put following into both source and destination page/component constructor/ngoninit

```
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => {
  return false;
};
```

also i applied NgZone

```
this.ngZone.run(() => {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
  });
```

but nothing seems work to fire ngoninit or constructor after using router.navigateByUrl()

can anyone please help.

Comment: could you please tell did my answer worked or not?

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use ionViewDidLoad. use like below

```
 ionViewDidLoad() {
   // your ngoninit function's code 
  }
```

For details check Ionic navigation lifecycle events.
https://ionicframework.com/blog/navigating-lifecycle-events/

Comment: i am not using NavController so this method is not fired

Answer (score 1):

We can invoke **ngOnInit** or **Constructor** every time by using **this.navCtrl.navigateBack(Ionic's)**. If we don't use(navigateBack) we can't invoke ngOnInit or Constructor.

(why ngOnInit doesn't invoked every time) :: when a route enters in stack in ionic framework(**it stores routes inside stack** )doesn't reintialize from  starting

**navCtrl.navigateBack** it will make all existing pages in the stack will be removed, and the navigated page will become the single page in the stack.

[invoking ngOnInit & constructor stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/pallamollasai/IonicAngular)

[invoking ngOnInit & constructor github](https://github.com/pallamollasai/IonicAngular)

**Note:** check console.logs in above mentioned urls. (check .ts files inside 'home' & 'list' folders)

Comment: Worked for me :)